# font-family not read correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/qYR6U/8/ - where I set the `font-family` with jQuery and read it back with jQuery. If the `font-family` I set is "Arial . . ." it comes back okay, in a single set of double quotes.  But if the `font-family` I set is "Comic . . ." it comes back in a set of double quotes enclosed inside of a set of single quotes.

This only happens with Chrome.  Does anyone know what's going on?

```
$('#box').css('font-family', 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif');
var fontFamily1 = $('#box').css('font-family');
console.log(fontFamily1);

$('#box').css('font-family', 'Comic Sans MS');
var fontFamily2 = $('#box').css('font-family');
console.log(fontFamily2);
debugger;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when a font name has spaces, the browser is interpreting any string requiring quoting as needing quotes, and hence the quotes are added (which is appropriate for the browser to do). Why only Chrome appears to do this (normal) quoting when it's property is read back, you got me.

Try [`Times New Roman`](http://jsfiddle.net/qYR6U/9/), you get the same quoted string back.

From [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-family):

> To avoid mistakes in escaping, it is recommended to **quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters** other than hyphens:

```
body { font-family: "New Century Schoolbook", serif }

<BODY STYLE="font-family: '21st Century', fantasy">
```

Comment: I'm not having a problem setting the font-family. I can set arial . . . or comic . . . by specifying them in a single set of quotes. The problem is reading them back. The page has an option to save the current styles in the user's database record and when I read a comic style (or any style with spaces, you're right) I get '"Comic Sans MS"' which gets stored in the DB record. This breaks the PHP that loads the user's styles when they start up:
g.fontFamily      = '<?=$fontFamily?>' ;
where $fontFamily is the stored DB field that has the two sets of quotes.

Comment: If you don't want the quotes, strip them out when you read it back, or escape the string when you write it out to the script.

Comment: Yes, this works.  The extra quotes that Chrome puts around "spaced" font names are always single, so styles.fontFamily    = styles.fontFamily.replace(/'/g,''); cleans it up while leaving the normal double quotes.  - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quotes for the JS function arguments. To set `font-family` with a font that's name has multiple words, you should enclose the name in quotes, too.

So instead of using `'Comic Sans MS'` in your code, try `'"Comic Sans MS"'`. (Single and double quotes).
I believe the `Arial` one works because that's just one word.

EDIT: I might've misunderstood.
If the problem is that you have quotes around a string that you don't want to have quotes around, you just need to remove them by string manipulation.

Comment: I believe the double quoting you're describing isn't technically required when setting from Javascript (but probably a good idea if using a string with more than one family included). See: http://jsfiddle.net/qYR6U/10/

Comment: How do you mean, "double quoting isn't required". Aren't you providing an example with double quoting in your answer, too?

Comment: No, I'm demonstrating why the quotes are added. You're saying they have to be there, but read the quote from the W3 spec right above it. Especially if it's only *one* family name, it's not necessary (but doesn't hurt).

Comment: "when a font name has spaces, it needs to be enclosed in quotes" is what you state in your answer. In the conditions of the question, the asker is setting the font by JS, while using single quotes to enclose his strings. How does this situation not call for double quotes?

Comment: I can see that's confusing; I'll update it to be more clear. Read the W3 quote; it *explains* what you're guessing at. When it's not needing escape characters (as in Arial or other non-escaped needing text), that's why it doesn't need quoting (in CSS). Not because "it's one word". `sans-serif` is technically not one word, for example.

Comment: So your point is that you don't need quotes around the style's value if it has multiple words in it, but rather, you need them when the value has spaces in it..?

Comment: When set with Javascript, the quotes will be added by the browser, so they're not needed. When set with CSS, they are needed according to the recommendation from the W3 spec.